# UDP datagaram listener of GPS device PHP

Tags: php, sockets, gps, listener, server

I want create a PHP UDP socket Listener for capture the datagram which is send by GPS device 
i am trying to connect a GPS device to my PHP server the Device is GT06 by concox. I have a globe PHP server 
i am write this bt its not working. i am not getting where to start

```
$clients = array();
$port = 2390;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($socket,'119.18.62.132',$port);
socket_listen($socket);
socket_set_nonblock($socket);

while(true)
{
    if(($newc = socket_accept($socket)) !== false)
    {
        echo "Client $newc has connected\n";
        $clients[] = $newc;
    }
}
```

and how can i connect multiple client to server.
and how can i run the script on server 
Please Help me

GT06 protocols link is  [Protocols](http://www.iconcox.com/uploads/soft/140916/1-140916013225.pdf)

Comment: You need to run wireshark on your server and listen to every UDP packet received on the port connected to the network your GPS device is on.
If the dgrams are supposed to use the Internet, check that you do not have a switch / router that filters this kind of packet.